# Lua smooth damp/tween algorithm

Tags: lua

I am trying to make an FPS but I need help on how to do smooth damp on my gun. It currently follows the mouse's position exactly but I want it to take a second to get there. Like a delay. I need this in Lua and can't use libraries.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/kikito/tween.lua

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Did some thinking and came up with an algorithm. Basically, I took mouse's current position and then made an if statement saying that if the position changes then it takes that number and divides it by 5